# Run UNIX Executable from webpge with I/O

Tags: javascript, php, perl, unix

I have what OS X calls a "UNIX Executable File" (it has no extension, but it runs as a command line program), and I would like to put it on a Linux web server and have it run on a webpage button press with input and return the output.

If needed, I can supply the file and it's supporting files. I also have the source file in Ada, if required.

EDIT: also, the input can be entered along with the file name: e.g., if the input was "actor," the command could be `./words actor`

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: You can use shell-exec or backticks around a shell command "shift-tilda". However, if shell-exec is disabled by your hosting company it won't work. Although, to my knowledge that isn't guaranteed to work since it was compiled for OS X but you're going to try and run it on some flavor of Linux.

Comment: You can't run an OSX binary under linux, any more than you could play XBox games on a Playstation.  You'll have to build it for linux (if you have the source) or find a linux equivalent (if you don't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm going to make an assumption that by "Linux Web Server", that you are implying a LAMP server. So if that is the case, then you will want to look into the `exec()`, `system()` and `passthru()` functions in PHP. If you are passing user supplied data to pass to your program, be sure to read up on the adivice for sanitizing that input appropriately. You can read more here: http://php.net/function.exec

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use PHP you could simply use the `passthru` function (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php).

HTML:

```
<form action="file.php" method="post">
  Parameters:<br>
  <input type="text" name="params"><br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  passthru($_POST['params']);
?>
```

Hope that helps!